# ActiveModel::Serializer not being called when rendering json?

Tags: json, serialization, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to use active_model_serializers in Rails 4.0.0 to serialize my json responses. However, the AMS class does not seem to be getting called/used at all when I use

```
render json: user
```

I'm not sure if there is some configuration issue, or if I'm using namespaces incorrectly.

Gemfile has:

```
gem 'active_model_serializers', '0.8.0'
```

Controller (in app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb):

```
module API
  module V1
    class UsersController < API::V1::BaseController
      def show
        user = User.find(params[:id])
        render json: user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

UserSerializer (in app/serializers/user_serializer.rb)

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

But in the json response I'm still seeing the full object, i.e.

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Test","last_name":"User1","created_at":"2013-12-26T07:12:02.618Z","updated_at":"2013-12-26T07:12:02.618Z"}
```

I've tried everything from explicitly calling `render json: user, serializer: UserSerializer` to namespacing the serializer to API::V1 and the result is the same. Am I missing something here?

**Edit**: This was fixed by making my `BaseController` inherit from `ActionController::Base` rather than `ActionController::Metal`. Not entirely sure what was missing from `ActionController::Metal`, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on Rails3 and I had to add this line into the app initializer folder

```
ActionController::API.send(:include, ActionController::Serialization)
```

Check if you have to do something similar with yours like

```
ActionController:: Metal.send(:include, ActionController::Serialization)
```

Comment: Thx, I had a problem with 4.1.7 and the ActionController::API.send(:include, ActionController::Serialization) did the job.

Answer (score 1):

include ActionController::Serialization

in ApplicationController